# How to create a new column using R which says TRUE/FALSE if another column displays a specific value?

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is a simple dataset:

```r
mydf <- tibble(country = rep(c("UK", "US"), each = 3),
               date = rep(c("Day1", "Day2", "Day3"), times = 2),
               cases = seq(1:6))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  country date  cases
  <chr>   <chr> <int>
1 UK      Day1      1
2 UK      Day2      2
3 UK      Day3      3
4 US      Day1      4
5 US      Day2      5
6 US      Day3      6
```

I want to create a new column called "part_us" using `mutate()` where TRUE is displayed if the value in "country" is equal to "US" and FALSE if it's anything other than "US".

It's a simple task but I am still learning R and would be grateful for some help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ifelse()` inside `mutate()` on your `dplyr` pipeline:

```
library(dplyr)
#Data
mydf <- tibble(country = rep(c("UK", "US"), each = 3),
               date = rep(c("Day1", "Day2", "Day3"), times = 2),
               cases = seq(1:6))
#Code
mydf <- mydf %>% mutate(part_us=ifelse(country=='US',T,F))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  country date  cases part_us
  <chr>   <chr> <int> <lgl>  
1 UK      Day1      1 FALSE  
2 UK      Day2      2 FALSE  
3 UK      Day3      3 FALSE  
4 US      Day1      4 TRUE   
5 US      Day2      5 TRUE   
6 US      Day3      6 TRUE
```

Another way can be next: (Many thanks and credits to **@Qwethm**):

```
#Code 2
mydf <- mydf %>% mutate(part_us=country=="US")
```

Same output.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for - thanks :)

Comment: @Karima Great! Continue learning :)

Comment: You could also write it without the ```ifelse```: ```mydf %>% mutate(part_us=country=="US")```

Comment: @Qwethm It is a great suggestion, let me add to the post with credits to you!